# Strange PHP pagination behaviour

Tags: php

I'm trying to list sentences from a mysql database that contains an entered keyword. Below I have a php script called from `quoteme.html` that contains a submit form. When I submit a keyword using `quoteme.html` it lists only the first page. When I click "Next 10 Records" I get an empty page (only showing "Next 10 Records" link).
If I enter keyword in  query line like:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `text` WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST('freak' IN BOOLEAN MODE)LIMIT      $offset, $rec_limit";
```

it works well and lists sentences for all links

EDIT:

While

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `text` WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE)LIMIT      $offset, $rec_limit";
```

does only work for first page.

What is the diffrence between `freak` and `$q`? Why  `$q = $_GET['q'];` resets its value on the next page?

EDIT2:

I tried to debug the error, I placed the below code in php script after query line.

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($offset);
var_dump($rec_limit);
echo '</pre>';
```

`$_GET` variable disappears after first page, `$offset` and `$rec_limit` variables are ok.

So now how can I make `$_GET` last on the next pages?

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('quotes');
/* Get total number of records */
$q = $_GET['q'];
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM text ";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
$rec_count = $row[0];

if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
{
$page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
$offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
}
else
{
$page = 0;
$offset = 0;
}
$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `text` WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE)LIMIT      $offset, $rec_limit";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "SENTENCE :{$row['body']}  <br> ".
     "--------------------------------<br>";
} 

if( $page > 0 )
{
$last = $page - 2;
echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}
else if( $page == 0 )
{
echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}
else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
{
$last = $page - 2;
echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a>";
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Would anybody tell me what's wrong in my code?
Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer, but it's probably better to do paging with JavaScript.

Comment: I suspect `$_GET{'page'}` should be `$_GET['page']`

Comment: @woz, why is it better to do that in JavaScript?

Comment: You don't have to make a trip back to the server and run another query. It's faster for the user, lighter on your server, and depending on your situation, less code to write.

Comment: @andrewsi . I just tried your sugestion it doesn't work.

Comment: @woz But that means that you're loading more data per pageload.

Comment: @WayneWhitty Yea, but it's like a few k more of data upfront vs reloading the entire page every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it after hours of searching and moding the code. It's "$_GET" variable issue because it passes through URL. And in my code there were missing parts that redirecting variable through URL. I added a few exra code here, it works well. Thank you all the people who were trying to be of help.

Here is the moded part:

```
if( $page >  0 )
{
$last = $page - 2;
echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?q=$q&page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?q=$q&page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}
else if( $page == 0 )
{

echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?q=$q&page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}
else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
{
$last = $page - 2;
echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?q=$q&page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors.

First one isn't really an error, but it is confusing: change `$_GET{'page'}` to the official `$_GET['page']`.

Second: you add 1 to the page number. Why? If I, as a user, go to url.php?page=2 I want to see page two, not page 3.

And last: `$offset` should be `($page - 1) * $rec_limit`: Page 1 starts with offset 0, Page 2 starts at offset 10.

**edit** it now just passed into my mind: do you pass the `q` query parameter to subsequent pages as well? So your url should look like: `<myscript.php>?q=freak&page=3`. Because php doesn't save variables over requests, you should pass the query along with the page.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, unfortunately it didn't work. 
I'm just a beginner, getting along with trial and error method. It appears that something is going wrong with query parameters such as offset, limit or $q variable

Comment: just to be sure: are there more then 10 records in your db? ;) try the pagination first with a simple query, like `SELECT * FROM \`my_table\` ORDER BY \`some_field\` DESC LIMIT 0,10`, it's a good way to make sure your pagination logic works like it should

Comment: Database has millions of lines, I get it from IMDB quotes database

Comment: I think you got closer, when I run only php script with like "freak" page urls goes like simplestpaged.php, simplestpaged.php?page=0, simplestpaged.php?page=2, ... When I call it from quoteme.html with "$q" it goes like simplestpaged.php, simplestpaged.php, simplestpaged.php?page=0 but empty page.

Answer (score 0):

use this template code it works fantastic with me

```
$limit = 40; //how many results on a page
@$s = $_GET['s']; //current page
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "youruser", "yourpass", "yourdbase");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$qry = "SELECT ... FROM ... where  ... ";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
if ($numrows > 0) {
    // determine if s has been passed to script, if not use 0 
    if (empty($s)) {
        $s = 0; 
    } 
    $qry = "SELECT ... FROM ... LIMIT $s, $limit";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
    $count = 1 + $s;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { //the main loop
        // .
        // .
        // .
    }

    $currPage = (($s / $limit) + 1); 
    echo "<br />"; 

    //link to other results
    if ($s >= 1) { // bypass previous link if s is 0            
       $prevs = ($s - $limit);
       echo "&nbsp;<a href=\"yourpage.php?s=$prevs\">&lt;&lt;Prev Page</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
    }

    // calculate number of pages needing links 
    $pages = intval($numrows / $limit); 
    if ($numrows % $limit) { 
        $pages++; 
    } 

    //start page links
    $currentpage=($s / $limit + 1);
    if ($pages > 2) {
        for ($t = 1; $t < $pages + 1; $t++) {
            echo(" ");
            if ($t != $currentpage) {
                $news = ($t * $limit) - $limit;
                 echo("<a href=\"yourpage.php?s=$news\">");
            }
            echo($t);
            if ($t != $currentpage) {
                 echo("</a>");
            }
            echo(" ");
        }
    }

    // check to see if last page 
    if (!((($s + $limit) / $limit) == $pages) && $pages != 1) { // not last page so 
        // give â€nextâ€ link 
        $news = $s + $limit; 
        echo "&nbsp;<a href=\"yourpage.php?s=$news\">Next page&gt;&gt;</a>"; 
    } 

    $a = $s + $limit; 
    if ($a > $numrows) { 
        $a = $numrows ; 
    } 
    $b = $s + 1 ; 
    echo "<p><b>Showing results $b to $a of $numrows</b></p>"; 
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: I have similar prototype pagination scripts, it's not easy to apply them to my query. I already tried many of them an tried yours too with no success. Thanks.

Comment: got you now, why you are using $q = $_GET['q']; while you said it's a form which means you passing <form method="POST">

Comment: other thought..
change
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `text` WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE)LIMIT      $offset, $rec_limit";
to
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `text` WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST('" . $q.  "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)LIMIT      $offset, $rec_limit";

Comment: Here is my quoteme.html file
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>`

<form method="get" action="simplestpaged.php">
  <input type="submit" />
  <input type="text" name="q"/>
  
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: ` $sql = "SELECT * FROM text WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST('" . $q. "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit"` doesn't work.

Comment: you need an extra spce between MODE) LIMIT that's all :)
   $sql="SELECT * FROM `text` WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

Comment: :( It's not that, remember I said it worked in the first page.